# How can I achieve something like data list in react with following code structure

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have this requirement in react, here **.rows** is scrollable (has some fixed height).
Each **.row** has **input** field and list component to show as auto suggestion (datalist).
On focus, I need to show suggestions, below input and on select option, I need to reset suggestions, so that it will show respective suggestions.

Problem here is list is hiding inside scrollable component. Please help me to show this suggestions list even if I scroll.
I tried with datalist, but in react, event listeners are not getting triggered, on click datalist items.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);
  const showSuggestions = () => {
    setShow(!show);
  }
  return(
    <div className='outerMost'>
      <div>Some component</div>
      <div>One more component</div>
      <div className='rows'>
        <div className='row'>
          <input value='' />
          <div className='suggestions'>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='row'>
          <input value='' />
          <div className='suggestions'>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='row'>
          <input value='' />
          <div className='suggestions'>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='row'>
          <input value='' onClick={showSuggestions} />
          {show &&<div className='suggestions'>
            <ul>
              <li>option 1</li>
              <li>option 2</li>
              <li>option 3</li>
              <li>option 4</li>
              <li>option 5</li>
              <li>option 6</li>
              <li>option 7</li>
              <li>option 8</li>
              <li>option 9</li>
              <li>option 10</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          }
        </div>
      </div>
      <div><button>click me</button></div>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
.outerMost {
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
}

.rows {
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.row {
  position: relative;
}

.suggestions {
  position: absolute;
  background: beige;
  left: 0;
  width: 166px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though your suggestions are positioned absolute they are showing inside of the row because row's position is set to `relative`.  If you remove this from row, your suggestions will positioned outside of the row.

Comment: Thank you David Klinge, for quick response. It works.

Comment: when the rows is not scrollable. Once rows become scrollable, position absolute will show in overflow hidden area not relative to input element